# <script> tags - Will leaving/creating a space (< script>) reduce the threat of XSS?

Tags: php, xss, sanitization

I'm creating a chat widget for my web site. The users will be able to input straight text - no html.

In an effort to eliminate HTML tags *AND* to allow users to use "<" and ">", I am taking their input and sanitizing it using strip_tags() on the input and htmlentities() on the output to the users' screens --- using php. One problem is that if a user inputs "Russia<China" strip_tags() will greedily eliminate everything after the "<".

My question is ... if I use regex to create a space between a "<" and the next non-space character, will that help me eliminate the threat of XSS? Will it prevent a potential HTML tag to render on the user's screen?

Say, if something like this slips through:

< script type='text/javascript'>alert('some malicious code');< /script>

One advantage in creating that space (e.g. < script... >) seems to be that strip_tags() will leave the "<" alone.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: By `stripTags()` you mean `strip_tags()`? Also, what if your regex fails? `<<script>`, for example

Comment: yes, strip_tags(). Thanks. My thinking is that I would do a preg_replace() (global) to add a space after every "<". Then I would do a strip_tags() on the input just to be sure. I'm assuming that strip_tags() would leave alone something like "Russia < China". My hope was that "< script>" would not pose a XSS threat, but my gut tells me that I shouldn't be so sure of that......

Comment: I am doing an htmlentities() on everything that I output from MySQL DB (user entries) to the user's browser.

Comment: [You could test it](http://jsfiddle.net/LHrnK/).

Comment: What about <img src="nonexistent.gif" onerror="malicious javascript">? Use HTML-escaping, don't strip out tags.
Should users be allowed to discuss <script> tags in the chat? I think a chat message including "<script>" is a valid chat message. But I want it rendered as text, not HTML, so I have to escape whatever HTML is in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The added space is enough to stop tags from being stripped by `strip_tags`, [and from being rendered as HTML by browsers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tokenization.html#tag-open-state).

But at what point exactly would you use such a regular expression? If you add it after you've done `strip_tags()`, legitimate text will already have been stripped. If you add it before `strip_tags()`, there won't be any tags left to strip, so users will see the spaced HTML tags in text.

But if they're going to see (mangled) tags anyway, why are you doing this at all? You can just do [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars), which you have to do anyway.

Even a HTML parser isn't going to help you, because a HTML parser would consider the `<China` in your example a tag too.

And is the person typing `a<b` making a comparison, talking about HTML, trying to add emphasis, or trying to inject a malicious script?

Comment: The person would be making a comparison - e.g. Larry Bird<Michael Jordan. That message board meme is pretty popular, and I would like to allow users to use it, if possible. My impetus for using strip_tags() is from an article written by Chris Shiflett that recommended using a 'mature' PHP function to sanitize input. Your point is well taken about just leaving it as it is and having it show up in the output (escaped w/ htmlentities()/htmlspecialchars()). That would certainly identify anybody trying to insert XSS code into their input, wouldn't it?!

Comment: @broncozr Indeed it would. And if it's not a particularly technical site anyway, there will likely not be much HTML being posted. And the people that do try will find out quickly enough that it doesn't work... You'd really only need to think about sanitizing the input if you actually want to *allow* **some** HTML.

Comment: @broncozr Oh, and [Chris Shiflett also said](http://shiflett.org/blog/2007/mar/allowing-html-and-preventing-xss): "I detest commenting on blogs where my comment is passed through something like strip_tags(), effectively mangling what I'm trying to say." ;)

Comment: ha. Well, it was a pretty old article that I read, IIRC. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars). It's the only function you need for sanitizing HTML. XSS threats are obliterated provided you use it judiciously. Follow that with nl2br if you want to display multiple lines, otherwise the text will appear on one line.

strip_tags is ***never, ever, ever*** the right function for *sanitizing* HTML. At best, it will eat or mangle certain valid text. At worst, if the allowed_tags parameter is used, it won't sanitize anything because attributes are kept. It also doesn't prevent HTML entities.